# Detect polygon from drawing

Tags: c++, drawing

My app includes a feature which a user is allowed to draw on a body. I want to detect polygon vertices as if the user had used straight lines. [image: Original drawing]

The image above is the original drawing, and I would want to detect the shape of a Z. This is not for character or handwriting recognition, just to detect a no convex polygon.

What would be the best C++ way to achieve that?

This is not to detect if the polygon drawn is convex or not. It's to detect, from the entire drawing, the vertices that would create a straight-line polygon.

Comment: It's not the same question... I clarified it.

Comment: Some C++ maths libraries contain inflection-point detection (which is I'm guessing what you're wanting to do). Think of it as a parabola with inflection points. Inflection points are useful for shape identification with letters eg. Z has 2, first right-to-left, second left-to-right (in a particular coordinate reference system you set first). Just an idea.